# Multiple url purging Varnish issue

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have an issue with varnish purging :

Our application is very dynamic . 
So an event on Object A , will generate 10.000 Purges because Object A infos are present in all pages.

Object A is stats seller and Page are ads page .

We are managing this by an asynch http PURGE call to varnish from the php code using curl .

So we will have 10000 http call 
The urls cannot be calculated (so REgex is not an options )

I want to ask you guys , is there any possibility in varnish to do some Batch Purging (HTTP interface) ?

If not , what's the options that you test and works in a very dynamic application when model and events affect a lot your pages .

Thanks in advance 
Nabil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the purges through `varnishadm` would be your best bet. You could either tunnel commands through SSH (assuming you are dealing with a remote Varnish server) or allow remote access from your Web server to the Varnish server.

You can easily write your own shell script to run a batch purge using `varnishadm` or you could take a look at [Thinner](http://propublica.github.com/thinner/), which is a Ruby based purger written to do exactly what you're looking for.

The obvious alternative, which you have most likely considered already, is to re-write your App to include *Object A* in the URL or in a custom header (for example `X-Object: A`), so you could do the ban based on that header:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.request == "BAN") {
    ban("obj.http.x-object == " +  req.http.x-object);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ban through varnishadm (in Varnish 3) is the way to go. I put together a [Gist about working with it here](https://gist.github.com/aderowbotham/5517123)